# Copy constructor and "=" operator they are not printing a copy of List l

Tags: c++

I'm not sure how you code the copy constructor and "=" operator I don't know if using `info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM];` is wrong I'm still new to codding I just learned copy constructor and "=" operator so I'm not sure how to implement here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define MAXITEM 100
typedef float itemType;

class List
{
    private:
        int length=0;
        itemType info[MAXITEM]; 
    public:
        List()
        {
        info[MAXITEM];  
        }
        List(const List &x)
        {
            cout<<"copy exec";//testing if copy constructor is being exec
            info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM];
        }
        List & operator =(const List &x)
        {
            cout<<"= exec";//testing if = operator is being exec
            info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM];
            return *this;
        }
        ~List()
        {

        }
        bool boolisthere(itemType item)const
        {
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                if(info[i]==item)               
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;                                   
            }           
        }
        void Insert(itemType item)
        {
            info[length]=item;
            length++;

        }
        void Delete(itemType item)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                if(info[i]==item)
                {
                    info[i]=info[length-1];
                    length--;   
                }   
            }

        }
        void Print()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                cout <<info[i]<<" ";
            }
            cout<<endl;

        }
        int Length()
        {
            return length;
        }

};

int main()
{
    List l;

    l.Insert(3.5);
    l.Insert(2.1);
    l.Insert(6.8);
    l.Insert(4.3);
    l.Insert(7.5);
    l.Insert(0.2);

    l.Length();

    l.Print();

    l.Delete(4.3);
    l.Print();

    List l2(l);//copyconstructor call
    l2.Print();

    List l3;
    l3=l; //= operator call
    l3.Print();


}
```

Comment: `info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM];` is no good. Any hint given here would not be enough to fix your misconception. You better learn from a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM];` just copies a single item beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: can you please show me the fix with code,thanks.

Comment: Do you even need these operators (copy constructor assignment operator and destructor)?

Comment: tbh I could but I dont want to be responsible for someone doing cargo cult programming. I really think the best way to help you is by not providing you a working solution but refer you to good sources for learning c++

Comment: Completely agree with @user463035818  You should look up arrays in your book and understand fully what that line is doing

Comment: BTW, `info[MAXITEM];` in your constructor is also a bug. arrays don't work the way you think in c++.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP needs to read  [A good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Jake • your code is very nearly correct.  Just have to address a few problem areas (as already pointed out by others) and it should work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't your copy constructor or your copy assignment operator, the problem is that you are trying to copy the array  as a sigle element. In C++ this is not possible you have to copy every single element of the array one by one. So your line `info[MAXITEM]=x.info[MAXITEM]` becomes

```
for(int i=0;i < MAXITEM;++i)
{
   info[i]=x.info[i]
}
```

Or if you can use STL in your program you could use the standard algorithm copy.
`std::copy(std::begin(x.info), std::end(x.info), std::begin(info));`

Also in the example you have posted you are trying to access the first element after the array and that's undefined behaviour!

Comment: Not a perfect solution. It is better to use `std::copy`. It would make the code much cleaner,

Comment: @S.M. You are right, i completely that std::copy can be used with normal array. The answer has been updated, thank you !

Comment: The best solution would be to just use `std::vector<itemType> info;` or `std::array<itemType, MAXITEM> info;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Agreed. I do not know why beginners start learning C++ from raw pointers and arrays.